# convert c# to php curl and get token automatically

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I hove url for receive token with 'Talend api tester' Extention that when send request show headers and body that show token and another informations.
[image]

[image]

images of result request .
this token expire per 24 house and I receive new token to PHP by curl.
please aid me how to receive token of URL to curl PHP of headers.

this code correctly executed but I have per 24h or 1 day a new token and token expired and my code is incomplete and shoude automatically get token of headers and update token to above code. this code is a document that give for me: this code correctly executed but I have per 24 house a new token and token expired . this code is a document that give for me:

```
public string token()
{
    string token1 = "";
    try
    {            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) 
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                username = "USERNAME",
                password = "PASSWORD"
            });
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string result1;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result1 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var data1 = JObject.Parse(result1);
        token1 = data1["claims"]["token"].ToString();
        txt_token.Text = token1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txt_token.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    return token1;
}
```

I can not convert c# to php curl code .
this code request token after set username and password . I coding php and document request is java; request token after set username and password and create new token . after create new token per 24h is active and I set Authorization (token) manually to code php curl and correctly show result:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://webservice.irimo.ir/sajjadeh/dal/dws/public');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoi2YfZiNin2LTZhtin2LPbjCIsImlzcyI6ImlsaXlhLmNvLmp3dCIsImV4cCI6MTY0NjA0NzkwNiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJzaXN0YW5fdmFfYmFsb29jaCJ9.gXUk4lloxMScT4wurlkyzpIR8a0cIrKJozG11GTdigr4EqUnU4TumbwnPJyAf79mMmNQGEFRr4qqFLXrNWLiOg'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
// curl_setopt(hnd,  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
$result = json_decode($result, true, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Post your code/attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (details incl. errors.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered. You should also include any example/debug data as text instead of images.

Comment: "I can not convert c# to php curl code" - why can't you do that?